# postgres database does not exist after rename

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am not new to sql but I am to postgresql and I am having an issue with renameing database when using psql. Below is exactly what is happening.

```
psql -d postgres

postgres=# ALTER DATABASE db_1 RENAME TO db_2;
ALTER DATABASE

postgres=# \q
```

All appears to go well when renaming `db_1` to `db_2`

Now when trying to login to db_2

```
psql -d db_2 -U postgres

psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  database "db_2" does not exist
```

Equally if I try db_1

```
psql -d db_1 -U postgres

psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  database "db_1" does not exist
```

So I log back in:

```
psql -d postgres

postgres=# ALTER DATABASE db_2 RENAME TO db_1;
ALTER DATABASE

postgres=# \q
```

Again the rename works perfectly from `db_2` to `db_1`.

Now I can log back in to db_1

```
psql -d db_1 -U postgres

db_1=#
```

So I am trying to figure out why the database seems to return `does not exist` after renaming `db_1` to `db_2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this:

```
psql -d postgres

postgres=# ALTER DATABASE db_1 RENAME TO db_2;
ALTER DATABASE
```

Do:

`postgres=# \l`

to get list of databases.

Comment: ty this absolutely  solved me issue. It was an issue of case sensitivity. Apparently no matter what one types it is defaulted to lowercase - good to know.

Comment: @Bruce https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Glad it is fixed, still something is not adding up. You renamed to lower case ```RENAME TO db_2``` and connected to lower case ```psql -d db_2 -U postgres``` so there should not have been an error. FYI, you can have UPPER, MiXed case by quoting the database name in double quotes e.g.  "DB_2". The issue being you have to double quote it there after.